# Ansible, only disable existing users?

Tags: ansible

I have a list of users in a yaml files, with a flag: state.

If the flag is undefined or if it is != "absent", I create the user :

```yml
    - name: "create account for {{item.name}}"
      user:
        name: "{{item.name}}"
        create_home: no
        shell: "/bin/bash"
      loop: "{{users}}"
      when:
      - item.state is undefined or item.state != "absent"
```

and on the contrary, I disallow "absent" users to connect:

```yaml
    - name: "disable user {{item.name}}"
      user:
        name: "{{item.name}}"
        shell: "/sbin/nologin"
      loop: "{{users}}"
      when:
        - item.state is defined and item.state == "absent"
```

But How can I make it so that only existing users can be disabled ? (And not creating a user to set its shell as `/sbin/nologin`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Q: *"Only existing users can be disabled."*

A: To modify present users only, use [getent](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/getent_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-getent-module) to read /etc/passwd and create a list of present users. Then use it in the condition. For example

```yaml
    - getent:
        database: passwd
    - set_fact:
        users_present: "{{ getent_passwd.keys()|list }}"

    - name: "disable user {{ item.name }}"
      user:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        shell: /sbin/nologin
      loop: "{{ users }}"
      when:
        - item.name in users_present
        - item.state|default('present') == 'absent'
```

---

Note1: It's more robust to default state to 'present' instead of testing the existence of the attribute

```yaml
    - name: "create account for {{ item.name }}"
      user:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        create_home: no
        shell: /bin/bash
      loop: "{{ users }}"
      when: item.state|default('present') != 'absent'
```

---

Note2: The module [user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-user-module) doesn't complain that a 'name' isn't present when 'state=absent'. Hence, it's not necessary to test the presence of a user in this case. Simply disable the user. For example

```yaml
    - name: "disable user {{ item.name }}"
      user:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        state: absent
      loop: "{{ users }}"
      when: item.state|default('present') == 'absent'
```

Comment: If you look closely, you'll notice that I don't *remove* old users, I merely replace their shell with `/sbin/nologin`, but the second part of your answer tells me what I need to know.

Comment: Right. I updated the answer and shuffled the notes.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if a user exists with `getent` with `getent passwd {{ item }}`.

Below is an example playbook:

```
---
  - name: "Check if User exists sample"
    hosts: localhost
    connection: local
    vars:
      users:
        - nginx
        - root
        - user4
        - user3

    tasks:
      - name: "check for user in /etc/passwd"
        command: getent passwd {{ item }}
        register: check_user
        ignore_errors: yes 
        loop: "{{ users }}"
        register: all_checks
      
      - name: "iterate over checks"
        debug:
          msg:
          - "{{ item.rc }}"
          - "{{ item.item }}"
        when:
          - item.rc == 0
        loop: "{{ all_checks.results }}"
```

So in your case you need to modify the section of your playbook you posted like this:

```
tasks:
      - name: "check for user in /etc/passwd"
        command: getent passwd {{ item }}
        register: check_user
        ignore_errors: yes 
        loop: "{{ users }}"
        register: all_checks
      
      - name: "iterate over checks"
        user:
          name: "{{item.item}}"
          shell: "/sbin/nologin" 
        when:
          - item.state is defined and item.state == "absent"
          - item.rc == 0
        loop: "{{ all_checks.results }}"
```